# Get database cursor from Django's RawQuerySet

Tags: python, django

I have a sizable table (20M+) in Postgres am I try to do a raw Django query on it:

```
tweets = TweetX.objects.raw("SELECT * from twitter_tweet").using("twittertest")
```

I get a RawQuerySet fast, but when I try to iterate over its results it is grinding to a halt:

```
for tweet in tweets:
   #do stuff
```

Memory is steadily rising so I suspect the whole dataset is being transferred.
Is there a way to get a database cursor from `.raw` so I can iterate over the result set without transferring it all at once?

Comment: if this same query does not run fast from the pgsql prompt you should check the postgresql server first of all. Also I dont know how the Django ORM translate a "select * " but it's better to do a select colA,colB....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that it is rather difficult to persuade django/postgres to use database cursors. Instead it fetches everything and then put a client side iterator (called cursor) over it.

Found a solution [over](http://thebuild.com/blog/2010/12/13/very-large-result-sets-in-django-using-postgresql/) [here](http://thebuild.com/blog/2010/12/14/using-server-side-postgresql-cursors-in-django/) that explicitly creates a db cursor. Only downside is it does not fit into django models anymore.

```
from django.db import connections

conn = connections['twittertest']
# This is required to populate the connection object properly
if conn.connection is None:
    cursor = conn.cursor()        

cursor = conn.connection.cursor(name='gigantic_cursor')
cursor.execute("SELECT * from twitter_tweet")

for tweet in cursor:
    #profit
```