# How to iterate a large table in Django without running out of memory?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model whose table has millions of records in it.  I'm trying to do some emergency maintenance on all of the records in the table at a shell but I'm unable to do a `MyModel.objects.all()` without completely exhausting memory on my system.

Even a `pass` causes the OOM killer to be called, killing my process:

```
for ii in MyModel.objects.all():
    pass
```

The reason is because Django's `QuerySet` is trying to build up its "result cache", by building a list with *all* of my records in it, here:

```
# django/db/models/query.py
def _fetch_all(self):
    if self._result_cache is None:
        self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())  # <<<< this guy!
    if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
        self._prefetch_related_objects()
```

But my machine can't hold the whole list in memory.

Of course, iterating `.all()` on such a large table would be a terrible idea in a real app, so the scope of this problem is rather limited (maintenance activities) but it does come up from time to time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to try is using the [`iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) method on the queryset before iterating over it:

```
for ii in MyModel.objects.all().iterator():
```

Comment: Hmm, this does appear to get around the results cache but I'm still running out of memory (in `CursorWrapper.execute` in `django/db/backends/utils.py`)... So I guess the results cache isn't the only thing killing me, it's just the sheer number of records being fetched from postgres...

Comment: That surprises me, but I haven't dug fully into the details of where Django uses a cursor vs. where it pulls records into memory. Maybe one of the blog posts linked from this answer would help, if you can do your maintenance without actual model instances or are willing to convert the raw database records into models? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381695/get-database-cursor-from-djangos-rawqueryset
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors for the Django docs.

Comment: I'm calling methods on the model instances, but I can totally factor that work out, which was some work I was hoping to avoid.  Not really a big deal for the odd maintenance here and there.  I was just hoping there was a nice way to do this without dropping down to raw database records. oh well.

Comment: Come to think of it, you could probably use repeated slices to do it - queryset slices are implemented as offset/limit parameters on the underlying sql query, so `MyModel.objects.all()[0:100]` really only fetches 100 records, then fetch `MyModel.objects.all()[100:200]` etc with a new query. Obviously that's something of a pain but might be less bad than reworking the model methods. This is how Django pagination works, so it might help abstract that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/

Comment: The obvious warning if you do use slices/pagination is that you can't delete or add records in your maintenance, or make changes that would affect the sort order, since it reevaluates the query each time.

Comment: I'm wondering if `transaction.atomic()` combined with chunked querysets may deliver the desired low memory use while remaining atomic and thus reversible if anything goes wrong. However I don't understand why `iterator()` uses that much memory. I can see my Python process racking up GBs of memory while retrieving chunks of 2000 rows of about 1MB each. If the caching were PostgreSQL's, it wouldn't be Python growing in size.

Comment: @bluppfisk have you figured it out? I'm trying to trace the memory issues and the closest I got was due to prefetching combined with the json decoder/converters, where the decoder is called millions of times with the same record and python doesn't seem to free the memory?

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is to use Django's[`iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) method on the queryset before iterating over it. However, you must also wrap your query in a transaction.

```py
    with transaction.atomic():
        for ii in MyModel.objects.all().iterator():
```

This is because by default Django operates in "autocommit" mode, which means database cursors will have the `WITH HOLD` argument, causing common DB's like postgres to use the large tempfile.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3.X you can try some async tasks.

It may be useful to create a schedule fetch.

Something like this:

```
async def _fetch_all(self):
     if self._result_cache is None:
          self._result_cache = await list(self.iterator())  # <<<< this guy!
     if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
          await self._prefetch_related_objects()
```

To run your code:

```
import asyncio
my_model = MyModel()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(my_model._fetch_all())
```

But if you are using 2.7 you will need to create a async task with celery or try some tools to do that like [Django Async](http://www.kirit.com/Django%20Async/Using%20Django%20Async%20from%20your%20code).

Hope it helps.

[Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793961/asynchronous-signals-with-asyncio)